# How to skip one step in setInterval jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to skip a one step in jquery setInterval function

e.g

```
<script>
// start updating continuously
            var timer, delay = 3000; // time in milli seconds
                timer = setInterval(function(){

                    // do something for each iteration

                    // I want to do this only once
                    if(result["pass"]){
                        $("#test").append("<li>Passed</li>");
                    }

                    // do something for each iteration

                }, delay);
</script>
```

how can I skip one or more than one steps to happen if they are happened once.
I want to skip only when it happens once. e.g if the condition is true in 101st iteration then it will not happen in first 100 iterations but if condition is still true in 102nd iteration, it should not happen because it happens in 101st iteration.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
// start updating continuously


            var timer, delay = 3000; // time in milli seconds
            var alreadyAdded=false;

                timer = setInterval(function(){

                    // do something for each iteration

                    // I want to do this only once
                    if(!alreadyAdded && result["pass"]){
                        $("#test").append("<li>Passed</li>");
                        alreadyAdded=true;
                    }

                    // do something for each iteration

                }, delay);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of where you can use a closure. You can create a function that returns a function.

This allows you to declare a variable in the scope of the outer function, which can then be accessed by the inner function.

```
 function getIntervalHandler() {
      var hasPassed = false;
      return function() {
          if(!hasPassed) {
           if(result["pass"]){
                    $("#test").append("<li>Passed</li>");
                    hasPassed = true;
                }
          }
      };
 }
 timer = setInterval(getIntervalHandler(), delay);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Thumbs up! But I did not try your code sir, the other concept works.